# Save image from camera without being resized

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I use the following code to create image file and save them in to sd card

```
 private File createImageFile(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                PICNAME,
                ".png",
                storageDir);
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
```

The issue is that, though I take picture in full screen mode but the above code always saves the image in very less amount of dimension which is 320x240. why so.. is there by any means that I can save the image without resizing?

Comment: Your function saves a bitmap to file. And nobody knows where you got the bitmap from. Your code has nothing to do with taking a picture with the camera.

Comment: It will never throw an IOExeption as you catch that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this :

```
public static Uri takePhotoByCamera(Activity activity) {
    File publicDirectory = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/myFolder");
    double d = new Random().nextDouble();
    File file = new File(publicDirectory, d + ".jpg");
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "New Picture");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
    activity.getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
    if (!publicDirectory.exists())
        publicDirectory.mkdirs();
    else if (!publicDirectory.isDirectory() && publicDirectory.canWrite()) {
        publicDirectory.delete();
        publicDirectory.mkdirs();
    } else {
        Log.d("tag550", "can't access");
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCamera);
    return photoUri;
}
```